# Не понимаю почему с плагином Telebot, бот при нажатие кнопки Stats не пишет статы которые написаны в коде

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def buttonforpers(message):
    if message.text == 'Invoker':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
        btn10 = types.KeyboardButton('Stats')
        btn11 = types.KeyboardButton('Skins')
        markup.row(btn11,btn10)
        btn12 = types.KeyboardButton('Bild')
        markup.row(btn12)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """\tInvoker
Магия в своей самой ранней, даже можно сказать, самой мощной форме, всегда являлась в основном искусством памяти.
""", reply_markup=markup)
        if message.text == 'Stats':
            bot.send_message(message.text.id,'1 б 34')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    if message.text == 'Invoker':
        ...
        if message.text == 'Stats':
            ...
```

И как по-вашему должен сработать второй `if`? Чтобы попасть к нему нужно, чтобы сработал первый `if`, а в этом случае `message.text` будет не таким, какой нужен для срабатывания второго `if`.

Я думаю у вас типичная проблема с отступами, уберите лишние отступы у второго `if` и блока кода после него:

```py
    if message.text == 'Invoker':
        ...
    if message.text == 'Stats':
        ...
```